# How to debug a Rsweave

Tags: r, sweave, pdflatex

I have an `rsweave` file that I run almost twice a week. Last time I used it a change a couple of things and when I run it to compile to pdf I got the following errors:
[image]
The pdf compiles complitly, and the only thing I notice that the error did is that the the pdf output has a extra page (the first one) all blank. I don't know how to make a reproducible example of the errors because I don't know whats the cause of it. But any way I just want to know generally how to debug a `rsweave` file when getting latex error like the ones in the picture

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/how-to-trace-latex-errors-efficiently) as a starting point. If you can *diff* your last successful compilation that may expedite your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say how you are running `Sweave`, but that looks like RStudio.  To debug something like this, just run `Sweave` explicitly in the R console, e.g. if your input file is `source.Rnw`, run

```
Sweave('source.Rnw')
```

This will produce `source.tex`.   Open that file in a text editor and look at the start of it.  You will see that `\Schunk` is used on line 27, but `\begin{document}` doesn't occur until sometime later.

My guess is that you added some text or a code chunk to the header.  All text belongs after `\begin{document}`.

Edited to add:  It turns out from the comments below that you were using `print(...)` in a code chunk before `\begin{document}`.  In Sweave, `print` output goes into the document.  If you want a message to show up in the console log but not the document, use `message("some text")`.  You'll also need to suppress the echoing of the command if you want to do this in the document header.  For example,

```
<<echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
message("Started at ", Sys.time())
@
```

will result in something like this in your console log:

```
 1 : keep.source term hide (Untitled.Rnw:6)
Started at 2017-09-27 08:28:33
```

and nothing in the document.

Comment: yeah that work and I see the text before the begin document, but it's a `print` I put in a function to know how long it is going to take to compile.  So is there a way to use `print` lets say in a loop and not get the errors that I get?

Comment: @alejandroandrade: Are you `print`ing to the console, or to the document?

Comment: @Werner I'm `print`ing to console or at least that's what i think

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280801/how-can-i-print-to-the-console-when-using-knitr for how to write to the knitr console.

Comment: @user2554330 but it's to Knitr so i would have to change the script. Is there a way for Rsweave?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot you were using `Sweave`.  Just use `message("some text")` and it will appear in the Sweave log but not in the document.