# Hide printing statement in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to hide printing statements in RMarkdown? I have written a function, which prints progress about the learning behavior of an algorithm to the R console. Here is an example:

```
f <- function() {
  print("Some printing")
  return(1)
}
```

In RMarkdown I have

````
```{r, eval = TRUE, results = "show"}
res = f()
print(res)
```
````

This adds "Some printing" and 1 into the RMarkdown output file. Is there a way to suppress "Some printing", but keep the output of the function (here 1)? For warnings, errors and messages there are options, but I could find none for print statements.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39289337/496488) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `message` in your function instead of `print`, you can suppress the message

````
```{r} 
f <- function() {
    message("Some printing")   # change this line
    return(1) 
}

res <- f()    
print(res)    # original prints both  
```
#> Some printing
#> [1] 1
````

either explicitly with `suppressMessages`:

````
```{r} 
res <- suppressMessages(f())
print(res) 
```
#> [1] 1
````

or via the `message=FALSE` chunk option:

````
```{r, message=FALSE} 
res <- f()
print(res) 
```
#> [1] 1
````

Messages designed for this kind of use. If you really want to keep `print`, you could subset (which is awkward), or use `capture.output` to capture and store the message while storing the result in another variable:

````
```{r}
f <- function() {
    print("Some printing")
    return(1)
}

trash <- capture.output(res <- f())   
print(res)
```
#> [1] 1
````

...but that's still pretty awkward.

Comment: Using `message` is probably the easiest solution. Though I personally don't like the red color with which it prints into the R console. Looks like an error...

Comment: Yeah, some better highlighting would be nice, though unless you've set similar highlighting on your knitted result, it will all probably just be gray. You can always see the difference between messages and errors, though, because an error is always preceded by "Error" like the results of `print` are preceded by an index, e.g. `print('foo'); cat('foo\n'); message('foo'); stop('foo')`. I'm sure it's possible to write a custom hook to differentiate printing, but it's not an easy thing to do.